# converting constructor: How do you explain a function given different arguments in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the following code. My problem is with the function f(). I don't understand why when we passed an integer argument we didn't have a compilation error.

The function  `void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A())` has two const parameters which are passed as reference to class A. in the main function we call f(3). I really didn't understand what happened exactly.

i couldn't find a correct title for the question. Is there a technical word for what is happening in here?

---

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0)
        : m_n(n)
    {
        std::cout << 'd';
    }

    A(const A& a)
        : m_n(a.m_n)
    {
        std::cout << 'c';
    }

private:
    int m_n;
};

void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A())
{
}

int main()
{
    A a(2), b;
    const A c(a), &d = c, e = b;
    b = d;
    A *p = new A(c), *q = &a;
    static_cast<void>(q);
    delete p;
    f(3);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid that: `explicit A(int n = 0)`

Comment: Try adding 'explicit' before your constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object of `A` gets created implicitly. To avoid such confusing cases, declare constructor [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). It is also considered as a good practice in general.

```
explicit A(int n = 0)
```

The standard (`N4140 12.3.1/1`) says:

> A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` specifies a conversion from the types of its
>   parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     X(int);
>     X(const char*, int =0);
>     X(int, int);
> };
>
> void f(X arg) {
>     X a = 1; // a = X(1)
>     X b = "Jessie"; // b = X("Jessie",0)
>     a = 2; // a = X(2)
>     f(3); // f(X(3))
>     f({1, 2}); // f(X(1,2))
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Comment: what happened exactly. Sorry i didn't understand;

Comment: @HaniGotc -- `A` has a constructor that takes an `int`.  You gave the function an `int`, and `A` happily was constructed using it.   To stop this from happening, `explicit` should be used.  Don't know how more simply to state this.

Comment: @HaniGotc I added a sample from the standard. It even uses the same function name and the same parameter value ).

Answer (score 5):

In c++, a constructor with only one parameter is known as a *converting constructor*. The reason the function doesn't complain is because the copy operation needed to pass the value into `a1` is making use of `A(int n = 0)` implicitly.

Stop this from happening by marking it `explicit`

```
explicit A(int n = 0)
```

As a side note; it is generally considered good practise to always mark single parameter constructors explicit unless you really want that behaviour (why?!)

Comment: [*"Converting Constructor"*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) not "implicit copy constructor"

Answer (score 3):

There exists a constructor for class A that takes an int so this constructor can be used to convert the parameter to the correct type. The compiler is allowed to do this once for each parameter.
Prefixing the **explicit** keyword to the constructor prevents the compiler from using that constructor for implicit conversions
Solution:
define

```
explicit A(int n = 0)
```